# bash/awk script to compare the content all the files in two different folders

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, awk

I have 2 diff directories in a Linux server wherein .csv files from two diff servers keeps on coming. The file name of the files in both the directories is same.
I want a bash/awk script which picks the set of same files from both the folders and read the content inside them.
If all the records inside both the files are same, it should continue with the next set of files, or else if there is a difference in any of the record, it should redirect only that record into another file name say $filename_diff.
I am a new learner of bash and awk, and after lots of try, I was only able to make the below code which is NOT running at all :(

```
#!/bin/bash

for file1 in $(ls -rlt /var/opt/dir1/*.csv | awk '{ print $9 }')
do
for file2 in $(ls -lrt /var/opt/dir2/*.csv |awk '{ print $9 }')
do
if [["$file1" = "$file2"]]
then
awk 'BEGIN {FS==","} NR == FNR{arr[$0];next} ! ($0 in arr)' $file1 $file2 > /var/opt/diff/`echo "$file2"_diff`
else
echo "To NULL" > /dev/null
fi
done
done
```

Please help in providing a solution to this.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Wrong in a few places. Use simple glob expansion in your first for loop `for file1 in  /var/opt/dir1/*.csv; do ... done`.  You only compare files if they have the same basename, so form the second filename based on the first: `file2=/var/opt/dir2/$(basename "$file1")`. You compare two strings with `[[` using `==`, not `=` (you use `=` with `/bin/[`). And you want to make sure `$file2` exists with: `if [[ -e "$file2" ]];` Should you not use `/usr/bin/diff` to compare contents?

Comment: What are you really trying to to achieve? (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) If you want to compare the the content of two directories, why is `diff --recursive dir1 dir2` not sufficient?

Comment: Hi Micha, thanks for the reply ... I cannot use diff because although it will show me the files which are different but, will not tell which particular record is different in that file (as I have thousands record in one file), also the redirection of the different record is a challenge in diff ...

Hey init_js, thanks for your reply as well ... please let me check and formulate the script as advised by you. I will get back to you.

Comment: What do you mean by "which record"? `diff` shows the differing line in both files as well as the line number. There is an option to extract context from a previous line if necessary. What more could you possibly need?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file1 in /var/opt/dir1/*.csv
do
    name1=$(basename "$file1")
    file2="/var/opt/dir2/$name1"
    [ -f "$file2" ] || continue
    cmp -s "$file1" "$file2" && continue
    diff "$file1" "$file2" | sed -e '/^[^>]/d' -e 's/^> //' >/var/opt/diff/"${name1}_diff`
done
```

That is,

- do not use "ls" to get a list of filenames
- only one loop is needed
- the `diff` program can (as noted in comments) give the information needed by selecting the '>' lines from its default output.
- the pathname given for the output filename seems incorrect (I removed the unneeded directory portion).

Answer (score 0):

@init_js:- the changes you recommend worked for me. below is the working script,

```
#!/bin/bash

for file1 in /var/opt/dir1/*.csv
do
file2=/var/opt/dir2/$(basename "$file1")
if [[ -e "$file2" ]]
then
awk 'BEGIN {FS==","} NR == FNR{arr[$0];next} ! ($0 in arr)' $file1 $file2 > /var/opt/diff/`echo $(basename "$file1")_diff`
fi
done
```

I dont understand one thing, why the "file2" variable was not declared as file2=$(/var/opt/dir2/$(basename "$file1")); because usually we declare variables with $(command) only, isn't it ?